# C# - Recursive series

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a question in recursion in `C#`.
My task is to print this:
1 2 3 4 5 @ 10 8 6 4 2 1

I have successfully printed this:
`1 2 3 4 5 @ 10 8 6 4 2 0`
However, I need to turn the 0 into 1.

This is my code:

```
public static void Recursive(int a, int b)
        {
            if (a > b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("@");
                Console.WriteLine(a * 2 - 2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                Recursive(a + 1, b);
                Console.WriteLine(a*2-2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you been given specific rules to implement or just a result you need to produce?

Comment: Result that I need to produce. No specific rules.

Comment: So the only constraints are that you need to write a recursive method that outputs that result?

Comment: Yes. I just need to output this result with recursion.

Comment: What is your question about recursion? As it stands your question is about how to achieve a specific output (as part of a class I presume) and nothing relating to the mechanics of recursion in C#. Please do not treat [SO] as a code writing service, but rather as a Q&A forum as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how your "need turn 0 into 1 (while printing)" is related to recursion, but some basic condition should do - I'd introduce a helper method as you seem to need it 3 times:

```
static void PrintOneInstedOfZero(int v) => Console.WriteLine (v == 0 ? 1 : v);
```

And use it correspondingly in all 2.5 places (the `Console.WriteLine(a*2-2);` is repeated twice for no obvious reason, so I count it as 1.5 calls) in your code:

```
public static void Recursive(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("@");
        PrintOneInstedOfZero(a * 2 - 2);
    }
    else
    {
        PrintOneInstedOfZero(a);
        Recursive(a + 1, b);
        PrintOneInstedOfZero(a * 2 - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: (You could move "the * 2 print" from both "then" and else.statement to after the if-else.)

Answer (score 0):

I have two variants to experiment with:

```
static void Recursive1(int level)
{
    if (level < 6)
    {
        if (level > 0)
        {
           Console.Write($"{level} ");
        }
        Recursive1(level + 1);
        if (level == 0)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("1 ");
        }
        else
        {
           Console.Write($"{2 * level} ");
        }
    }
    else if (level == 6)
    {
        Console.Write("@ ");
    }
}

static void Recursive2(int level)
{
    if (level < 6)
    {
       Console.Write("12345@"[level] + " ");
       Recursive2(level + 1);
       Console.Write($"{(level == 0 ? 1 : 2*level)} ");
    }
}
```

The second variant is probably not what you are supposed to hand in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take. [output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEm8yn) for reference.

```
public static void Recursive(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        Console.Write("@ ");
        Console.Write(a * 2 - 2);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(a + " ");
        Recursive(a + 1, b);
        if (a > 1)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.Write(a * 2 - 2);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.Write(a);
        }
    }
}
```